# Driving LED with PMDXB600UNE MOSFET from FPGA, MOSFET never turns on

Tags: mosfet, led, fpga

## LED was placed rotated 180 degrees during assembly.
So now my question is will this circuit work or should I change it in anyway?

I do realize similar questions have been asked, but I think my problem is unique because of the MOSFET I'm using.

Design: Drive a set of 7 RGB LEDs with 21 PWM from a Machx02 FPGA.  LED I=20mA, Vf=3.3V to 4.0V.
I chose the PMDXB600UNE dual MOSFET for package size and electrical characteristics (specifically Vgs turn-on is from 0.45 to 0.95V).  Vgs of 1.8V allows Id=100mA

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fdXcTM.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

MEASUREMENTS:  Vgs=0.1V  Vds=0V
MOSFET is correct on layout.

Can someone check my LED layout.  The data sheet doesn't specify footprint view is top down or bottom up. The first picture seems to be the top and then the pins match my footprint.  But the 3rd picture is a mirror.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: please add a clear, answerable question to your post

Comment: What are your Vgs & Vds measurements?

Comment: Could this be a layout bug?

Comment: QUESTION:  Why doesn't the MOSFET TURN on with 1.8V (I even went up to 3.3V) on the gate?  Is the MOSTFET diodes causing a problem?

Comment: Checking the layout and getting accurate measurements on the Vgs and Vds.

Comment: Vgs = 0.1V  Vds = 0V   I verified the 5V.  I verified the layout of the MOSFET is correct (checked package against layout).

Comment: If Vds is 0V, then the MOSFET *is* turned on. But with Vgs only 0.1V, it should not be. As such, your question doesn't make any sense. Please verify your measurements.